# MS Sql Restore DB from backup failed (replication)

Tags: sql-server

I have a standalone copy of a production db on my PC that I use for future development of the web frontend. Every now and then I restore the copy db from an up to date backup of the production db. This worked. Unfortunately since the last restore the production has had replication configured and now when I try and do a restore I get the following error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Restore failed for Server 'MyPCName'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid object name 'MSreplication_subscriptions'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I have tried various options but without any joy.

Any help appreciated

**Note:** Just in case it matters... the production sits on a SQL2005 server whereas my PC has SQL2008 R2 but this has not caused issues before.

Comment: How are you executing the restore? Manually, with SQL? Can you share that? Are you doing it with SSMS? Are you checking the "WITH KEEP_REPLICATION" option in SSMS?

Comment: Using SSMS and yes I did use the WITH KEEP_REPLICATION option.

Comment: I also have the Overwrite option ticked

Comment: I would try it without the KEEP_REPLICATION option.

Comment: Tried again with the following Options... WITH REPLACE and RESTORE WITH RECOVERY and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK fixed it. I dropped the database completely and then let the restore create a new db. It still gave me the replication error but the db was created albeit in Single User Mode. Changed to Multi User and everything was OK.